# Is this formula for 2D Fourier integral of diffraction kernel correct?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis, image-processing

Well I have a function parametrized by $z$
$$g_z(x,y) = \frac{z}{i \lambda r^2} e^{i k r}, \quad r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},$$
where $\lambda > 0$ is real constant and $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. This is the convolution kernel in Rayleigh-Sommerfield integral in the diffraction theory, where we are interested in the 2D convolution of this kernel with known function $\psi_0$
$$\psi_z(x,y) = \psi_0(x,y) * g_z(x,y).$$
Of course from the perspective of convolution theorem would be nice to know explicitly Fourier transform of $g_z$, but I was skeptical if such closed formula does exist.

I have found [the article](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.47.003481), formula (3), claiming that the fundamental result of scalar diffraction theory was to find 2D Fourier transform of $g_z(x,y)$ so that

$$G_z(\xi_x,\xi_y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_z(x,y) e^{-2 \pi i (\xi_x x + \xi_y y)}  \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y,$$

where
$$G_z(\xi_x, \xi_y) = e^{i k z \sqrt{1 - (\lambda \xi_x)^2 - (\lambda \xi_y)^2}} , \quad (\lambda \xi_x)^2 + (\lambda \xi_y)^2 < 1 $$
and
$$G_z(\xi_x, \xi_y) =  0, \quad (\lambda \xi_x)^2 + (\lambda \xi_y)^2 \geq 1.$$

That result is also being described in [Introduction to Fourier Optics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Fourier_Optics.html), page 60, chapter The Propagation Phenomenon as a Linear Spatial Filter, eq 3-73.

I did not yet went fully through the derivation but I wonder that Fourier transform of exponential phase function $g_z$ can have finite support. Maybe dividing by $r^2$ does the trick. How to show that $FT(g) = G$?

Comment: for $\xi_x=0=\xi_y$ I find an exponential integral answer for $G_z$, not this simple $e^{i\alpha z}$; I also cannot find this integral formula  in the cited paper (which I downloaded from https://webpages.tuni.fi/lasip/DDT/pdfs/Frequency_DDT.pdf )

Comment: Its the formula (3) in the referenced preprint and in the paper as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed this.

Comment: Turns out that result being described in books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Fourier_Optics.html, page 60, chapter The Propagation Phenomenon as a Linear Spatial Filter, eq 3-73. I will try to understand this.

Comment: I looked into that book: the calculation assumes $kz\gg 1$, since it neglects evanescent waves; the compact support of the Fourier transform only applies in that approximation.